# Reading input using command in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a string into my program from the terminal. So the command I want to use is eg  `g++ -g -std=c++11 main.cpp -o out` to compile, then `./out < file.txt` to run my program. But I, however, get an error when I use a `<` symbol when running my program.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  cout << "Checking this " << argv[1] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I want my program to output `Checking this file.txt` but I want to run it this way, `./out < file.txt` NOT THIS AWAY `./out file.txt`

Comment: You must've misunderstood your program's requirements. As described this is not possible. Do you understand the difference between `<file.txt` and `file.txt`, after the name of the executable program? What each one does, and how it works?

Comment: `argv[1]` means the first command-line argument (after the name of the executable itself). When you run your program using `./out file.txt`, there is one argument (`file.txt`), so you have `./out` in `argv[0]` and `file.txt` in `argv[1]`. But if you run it using `./out < file.txt`, there are no arguments at all (the `<` tells the shell to redirect input, this is not an argument for your program to see). So, in that case you still have `./out` in `argv[0]`, but this time there is no `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with this configuration. You would have to run the program as `./out file.txt` and then have the program read in from file.txt which will have the file name stored in `argv[1]` assuming this order.

POSIX compliant shells when you run `./out < file.txt` will just give your program the contents of file.txt in stdin. The `< file.txt` part is not visible to your program.